# Reportlab, orientation of a frame

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab, platypus

my documents has several portrait and several landscape A4 pages. Basically I would like to have all of my pages in the same portrait layout, but for those in landscape i would like to rotate the frame orientation by 90deg, so in the end I will have same headers/footers on all pages (only body of some pages will rotate). 
How can I achieve this ?

Below is my very first draft of layout, I use custom canvasmaker because i want to have page x of total. 
https://pastebin.com/jip0Pb61

```
_margin_top = 10*mm
_margin_bottom = 30*mm
_margin_left = 20*mm
_margin_right = 50*mm
_footer_height = 30*mm
_header_height = 20*mm

class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    """
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546511-page-x-of-y-with-reportlab/
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576832/
    """
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Constructor"""
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def showPage(self):
        """
        On a page break, add information to the list
        """
        self.pages.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def save(self):
        """
        Add the page number to each page (page x of y)
        """
        page_count = len(self.pages)

        for page in self.pages:
            self.__dict__.update(page)
            self.draw_page_number(page_count)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)

        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        """
        Add the page number
        """
        page = "Page %s of %s" % (self._pageNumber, page_count)
        self.setFont("Helvetica", 9)
        self.drawCentredString(210*mm/2, 10*mm, page)


class FrontCoverTemplate(PageTemplate):
    def __init__(self):
        frame  = Frame( _margin_left, _margin_bottom+_footer_height, 210*mm-(_margin_left+_margin_right), 297*mm-(_margin_top+_margin_bottom+_header_height+_footer_height), id='main_frame', showBoundary=1,rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        PageTemplate.__init__(self, id='first',frames=[frame], pagesize=A4)

    def beforeDrawPage(self,canvas,doc):
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        canvas.saveState()
        #header
        #draw header border
        canvas.setFillColorRGB(1,0,1)
        canvas.rect(_margin_left,297*mm-_margin_top-_header_height,210*mm-_margin_left-_margin_right,_header_height, fill=1)

        #footer
        canvas.setFillColorRGB(1,0,1)
        canvas.rect(_margin_left,_margin_bottom,210*mm-_margin_left-_margin_right,_footer_height, fill=1)
        canvas.drawString(_margin_left,_margin_bottom-10*mm, "My address")
        canvas.restoreState()


#to be updated
class LaterTemplate(PageTemplate):
    def __init__(self):

        frame  = Frame( 20*mm, 20*mm, 297*mm-40*mm, 210*mm-40*mm, id='main_frame', showBoundary=1,rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        PageTemplate.__init__(self, id='later',frames=[frame],pagesize=landscape(A4))



class DeviceMontageOrder():

    def __init__(self):

        self.buffer = BytesIO()
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Roboto', 'Roboto-Regular.ttf'))
        self.styles = getSampleStyleSheet()####styles
        self.moj_styl=ParagraphStyle('moj_styl',
                                alignment=TA_LEFT,
                                fontSize=8,
                                fontName="Roboto")
        self.maly_styl=ParagraphStyle('maly_styl',
                                alignment=TA_LEFT,
                                fontSize=6,
                                fontName="Roboto")
        margin = 0.8*cm
        self.doc = BaseDocTemplate(self.buffer)
        self.doc.addPageTemplates(
                [
                    FrontCoverTemplate(),
                    LaterTemplate(),
                    ])



    def get_info_page(self):
        elements =[]
        elements.append(Paragraph("Jedziemy gdzieśtam",self.moj_styl))
        return elements

    def get_device_page(self):
        elements =[]
        elements.append(Paragraph("Montujemy sobie cośtam",self.moj_styl))
        return elements

    def print_single_order(self):

        elements=[]
        elements.append(NextPageTemplate('first'))
        elements = elements + self.get_info_page()
        elements.append(PageBreak())
        elements.append(NextPageTemplate('later'))

        elements = elements + self.get_device_page()
        elements.append(PageBreak())
        elements = elements + self.get_device_page()
        print(elements)
        self.doc.build(elements,canvasmaker=PageNumCanvas)

        # Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
        pdf = self.buffer.getvalue()
        self.buffer.close()
        return pdf
```

Comment: One cannot run the code, it also misses imports, ideally you only cut and paste with a '__name__ == "__main__"' statement to quickly get into the problem. Nevertheless, have you played with 'canvas.rotate(90.0)'  ? Perhaps you first could draw you headers and footers using conditional application, such as     'a, b = pagesize
    if a < b:
        return (b, a)
    else:
        return (a, b)'

Comment: I've tried to add canvas.rotate(90.0) but since I wnat to fill my body with flowables I do not know, where I should put it (i've tried in various places in the beforeDrawPage method but with no luck). Could you please help me and tell where in the code I should rotate the canvas ?
What I would like to have is : https://imgur.com/a/98UXHHW

Comment: The idea I had in mind was that you first create head and footer in vertical layout directly on canvas, then you rotate the canvas and add flowables. I have no previous experience in this but was looking through the RL code for hints how to be able to always place header and footer in vertical layout. Good luck

Comment: Do you know how (and where) should I rotate canvas ? before I build my story with flowables ? How canI access canvas while having
   self.doc = BaseDocTemplate(self.buffer)

Comment: unfortunately not, when looking through the source code I found this rotate within a file called lto.py, located reportlab > graphics > barcode ,, the idea was to see header and footer as a graphic element, in the same way as the barcode in this case. If you create a project you can run as single file (with imports and if __name__ == "__main__":) and amend your question with it,  i can experiment a little, but else, it was just a thought of a potential solution